# Combining c++ algorithm with c# GUI

Tags: c#, c++

I have tracker algorithm which is implemented entirely in c++ (Am working with VS 2013 x64 on WIN7).

To actually plot the tracks on a world map I want to design GUI (in c#) which exploits the built in graphical library in C#, basically it should be figure with a map on it and I want to send it, periodically, the relevant list of tracks computed by the tracker.   Of course, I also want to be able to debug the C++ algorithm from VS while plotting the tracks.

Is there any tutorial which explains how to do that correctly? Is it even possible?

Comment: Is the C++ implementation also organized as a Visual Studio project?

Comment: In a single solution, add a dll c++ project and an exe c# project. Make your c# project depend on your c++ project. Export functions you would like to call from c#. Enable native code debugging in settings. Pinvoke needed functions. That's it.

Comment: @Codor - Yes, its a dll.

Comment: Read about [c++/cli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI). there is even [c++cli](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-cli) tag on SO

Comment: @V.Kravchenko - Thanx , will try that, it does sound simple...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use outer C++ `dll`s in C# like this:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string className, string windowTitle);
```

So you can just add the reference to your `dll` and  then call it from C# code.

I'm not sure if it will allow you to debug C++ code, but I guess you could check the V. Kravchenko comment and try to enable debugging like he mentioned.